# Enum types in hex are returning wrong values using Java?

Tags: java, hex

I am using the following enum types in the code below:

```
public static enum PanelType
 {
   PAS8((byte)0xA6), PAS83((byte)0xA7);

  private byte code;

  private PanelType(byte code)
  {
   this.code=code;
  }

  public byte getCode(){
   return code;
  }
 }
```

However, when I'm trying to use it here in my method:

```
 for (PanelType type:PanelType.values())
 {
   if (decoded[3]==type.getCode())
   return type;
 }
```

I am returning the incorrect value for the: `type.getCode()` method.  It's returning -90 instead of 166, which is what I'm expecting.

I know that FFFF FFFF FFFF FFA6 = -90, but why does 0xA6 get returned as negative number ?

Comment: It's because `byte`, as with all integer types in Java, is a signed value.

Comment: byte, short, int, and long are all signed. Only char is unsigned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`byte`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)s have a maximum value of 127 and a minimum value of -128. `0xA6` is 166 in decimal, so there is an overflow:

```
-128 + (166 - 127 - 1) == -90
```

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks I little bit forgot these things after graduating. Thanks for reminding !

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution is to not cast it to a byte in the first place.  This would make the code simpler and it will do what you expect.

```
public enum PanelType {
  PAS8(0xA6), PAS83(0xA7);

  private int code;

  private PanelType(int code) {
    this.code = code;
  }

  public int getCode() {
    return code;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is surely suggests how to get out of such situation, I'll upvote it as it contains useful advice. But the question was why 0xA6 gets treated as negative, and arshajii answered very nicely.

Comment: @Datenshi Yes. 0x80 to 0xFF are as negative when cast to a byte. The top bit is the sign.